# how to close imagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, dismiss

I just can't get this:

how in the world can I "shut down" imagePickerController on xcode?
This is the code that opens the camera, and it works perfectly..

```
-(IBAction) startcamera {


imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
imagePickerController.showsCameraControls=NO;
imagePickerController.toolbarHidden=YES ;
imagePickerController.wantsFullScreenLayout=YES;
imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView=self.view;
self.imagePickerController.delegate=self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
[imagePickerController release];
```

}

Ok now, say I want to close imagePickerController by clicking a button (means without picking any image): how am I supposed to do that?
Tried with:

```
-(IBAction)closecamera {


[imagePickerController release];
    [imagePickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

but it doesn't work!
Any clues?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't release `imagePickerController` twice.
2. You would dismiss it with `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

Don't release it twice and dismiss it before you release it. (like ole said)

But this is also important... as soon as you have released an object it is gone and no methods can be called.